# UV unwrap creates a weird single edge result

Tags: uv

I have a mesh which was decimated and UV unwrapped in zbrush, brought into blender to pack and optimize the UV's. Turns out, one of the islands is messed up and streched. (Sometimes this happens with zbrush meshes, normally I just select the problematic island and unwrap it again in blender, normally works well)

this is what came out of zbrush, streched and bad:
[image: this is what came out of zbrush, streched and bad]

When I try to unwrap it again in blender, this is what i get, super weird, only 2 edges?:
[image]

I'm out of solutions at this points and can't figure out what goes wrong here. I've tried removing doubles or marking the problematic island's border as a seam again and unwrapping, but nope.
Any suggestions are appreciated
Cheers

Comment: What kind of Unwrap method you used? Snapping enabled? Have you tried to reset UV's? ... for this king of topology it has to be pain to UV's :)

Comment: yes it's a huge pain! i'm just doing "U > unwrap". are there other methods of unwrapping in blender? I have tried resetting and doing U > unwrap again but here is the result: https://i.imgur.com/1POvH3G.png  that massive triangle is the whole mesh, and i think the initial problematic part is that weird edge again. what the hell is going on here? :D
also, i don't know about snapping.

Comment: When you press U you get bunch of options check the [reference Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/uv_image/uv/editing/unwrapping/index.html)

Comment: Ah damn I'm dumb. Just using the "project from view" worked really well - don't know why I never though of that! Thank you.